# Swift_TransportException (503) Expected response code 354 but got code "503" - Laravel

Tags: laravel, smtp, exchange-server, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to send emails using MS Exchange as smtp Server, that doesn't need any authentication and requires no encryption. this is my (.env) file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=servername
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

and the mail.php config file looks like the following:

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 25),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'email@domain.de'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Some name'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'username' => env(null),

    'password' => env(null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Log Channel
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------


    'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),

];
```

This app is running on MS Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS8, it was working fine locally on my Win10 system but when deployed on the server it started giving this error :

[image]

And when I telnet on the smtp server it gives the following:

[image]

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with swiftmailer version 6.2.3. The error occurred if I tried to send an e-mail like gaga@server.com. gaga is unknown, the server.com exists.

-> so I switched back to swiftmailer version 6.02.